# Javascript class change click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am an absolute JS noob and need a little help.
I am using bootstrap 3.1.1

```
<a class="" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".event-list-links" href="#collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
 <i class="icon-chevron-sign-down"></i>
 </a>
```

Now on clicking the link the  `.icon-chevron-sign-down` should change to `.icon-chevron-sign-up` how do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another try:

```
<i class="icon-chevron-sign-down" onclick="changeClass(this)"></i>
```

And the script:

```
function changeClass(e) {
  e.className = 'icon-chevron-sign-up';
}
```

And back to first try:

```
<i class="icon-chevron-sign-down" onclick="(function (e) { e.className = 'icon-chevron-sign-up'; })(this)">halo</i>
```

EDIT

To toggle between the two classes:

```
function changeClass(e) {
  if (e.className === 'icon-chevron-sign-up') {
    e.className = 'icon-chevron-sign-down';
  } else {
    e.className = 'icon-chevron-sign-up';
  }
}
```

Comment: Your second solution worked. But now I need the opposite behaviour too. That when my container collapses again, it switches back...

Comment: You mean when you click again it should go back to `icon-chevron-sign-down`? It added an edit to my answer.

Comment: Hi phylax, I tried but still don't get it :) - When I use the <i class="icon-chevron-sign-down" onclick="changeClass(this)"></i> together with your edited script in the pagefooter, nothing happens. The only thing working is you middle-line. What is the fitting html to yor function?

Comment: I created a plunker to demonstrate it: http://plnkr.co/edit/9Q1fZsMLcLhslMULUOJv?p=preview

Comment: 1. it works so far.
2. with a strange behaviour. 
For the first to clicks everything is ok. Then it skips on click, and continuing, leading the function to do it reverse afterwards. Maybe you have a look yourself on [link]http://www.my-home-is-my-kassel.de/#collapse-1612706[link] it is about the up / down sign below the calendar. Thanks!

Comment: I feared this would happen. Your side adds an extra class `collapsed` to the element which gets overwritten/removed when using `className`. Since you are using jquery i updated the plnkr to use jquery. This sould do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily with jQuery. You'll want to add a class to your  tag so you can select it:

```
<a class="toggle-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".event-list-links" href="#collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <i class="icon-chevron-sign-down"></i>
</a>
```

Then just add a click handler that removes the `icon-chevron-sign-down` class and adds a `icon-chevron-sign-up` class.

```
$'.toggle-link').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.icon-chevron-sign-down').
        removeClass('icon-chevron-sign-down').
        addClass('icon-chevron-sign-up');
    return false;
});
```

I'd note that this won't switch back to `icon-chevron-sign-down` if you click again. That code is a little more complicated. Let me know if that's what you're looking for and I'll update this answer.

Comment: `-sign-down` is not a class

Comment: I was avoiding having to type "icon-chevron-sign-down" over and over. I'll update my answer if that's confusing.

Comment: you've missed leading dotes in selectors.

Comment: Oops. Need more sleep. Updated

Comment: It sould switch in both direction, since it is a collapsing container.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setattribute

```
Var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
Firstelem=elem[0];
Firstelem.setAttribute("class","your clAss here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your class (IE8+) in `script` tag (place it jest before closing `body` tag):

```
document.onload(function() {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll('i.icon-chevron-sign-down');
    element.onclick(function(e) {
        element.className.replace('icon-chevron-sign-down'
                                , 'icon-chevron-sign-up');
    });

});
```